# How to determine a value in condition PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a code for determining a value of mathematics and physics.

**->for math scores:**
if value 0 - <50, then "Bad"

if value 50 - <75, then "enough"

if value 75 - <85, then "good"

if value 85 - <=100, "great"

**->for physics scores:**

if value 0 - <50, then "Bad"

if value 50 - <75, then "good"

if value 75 - <85, then "great"

if value 85 - <=100, "extraordinary"

if I enter physics scores=50 ,the result that I have like this:

```
"Your physics scores are bad"
```

and the source code:

```
   <?php
$value=50;
//choice:
$courses='physics'; //or 
$courses='math';

if($courses='math' and $value<50){
    $sentence_value='Your math scores are bad';}
elseif ($courses='physics') {
    $sentence_value='Your physics scores are bad';}
elseif
    ($courses='math' and $value<75){
    $sentence_value='Your math scores are enough';}
elseif ($courses='pyhsics') {
    $sentence_value='Your physics scores are good';}
elseif
    ($courses='math' and $value<85){
    $sentence_value='Your math scores are good';}
elseif ($courses='physics') {
    $sentence_value='Your physics scores are great';}
elseif
    ($courses='math' and $value<=100){
    $sentence_value='Your math scores are great';}
elseif ($courses='physics') {
    $sentence_value='Your physics scores are extraordinary';}

echo"Value : $sentence_value";
?>
<br />
```

And the result, if I enter math scores by 50 points, that i want like this::

```
"Your math scores are bad"
```

if I enter math scores by 70 points, that i want like this:

```
"Your math scores are enough"
```

if I enter math scores by 80 points, that i want like this:

```
"Your math scores are good"
```

if I enter math scores by 100 points, that i want like this:

```
"Your math scores are great"
```

if I enter physics scores by 50 points, that i want like this:

```
"Your math scores are bad"
```

if I enter physics scores by 74 points, that i want like this:

```
"Your math scores are good"
```

if I enter physics scores by 83 points, that i want like this:

```
"Your math scores are great"
```

if I enter physics scores by 98 points, that i want like this:

```
"Your math scores are extraordinary"
```

Comment: `==` is comparision, `=` is assignation.

Comment: `$courses` will only equal "math", never "physics" since you use the same variable name and re-define it from "math" to "physics" every time you run the script.

Comment: @dinidwirahayu check if my aswner solve your problem!, i gave to you a complete sample of what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues with the code.

```
<?php
$value=50;
//choice:
$courses='physics'; //or 
$courses='math';
```

At the end of this block, `$courses` will always have the value of `math`.

```
if($courses='math' and $value<50){
```

In this if statement, you are assigning the value `math` to `$courses`, which evaluated to true. However, `$value<50` evaluates to false (`50!<50`), so you pass to the next elseif.

```
elseif ($courses='physics') {
```

Here you assign the value `physics` to `$courses`, which returns true, so the next line is executed and you exit out of the if block.

Here is an if block that should work better:

```
if ($courses == 'math') {
  if ($value < 50) {
    //
  } elseif ($value < 75) {
    //
  } elseif ($value < 85) {
    //
  } else {
    //
  }
} elseif ($courses == 'physics') {
  if ($value < 50) {
    //
  } elseif ($value < 75) {
    //
  } elseif ($value < 85) {
    //
  } else {
    //
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using '=' to compare values, and this is wrong! '=' is using for assign a value to a variable, and '==' to compare values!
And you are assign and re-assign a value to the same variable, when you assign 'math' to courses, you lost the previous value 'physics', maybe you should input from user which course is and them assign to a variable!
 Take a look at the complete sample:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST[grade]) && isset($_POST[course])){ 
    $value=$_POST[grade];
    //choice:
    $courses=$_POST[course]; //or 
    if($courses=='math'){
        if($value<50){
            $sentence_value="Your $courses scores are bad";
        }
        elseif($value<75){
            $sentence_value="Your $courses scores are enough";
        }
        elseif($value<85){
            $sentence_value="Your $courses scores are good";
        }
        elseif($value<=100){
            $sentence_value="Your $courses scores are great";
        }
    }
    elseif($courses=='physics'){
        if($value<50){
            $sentence_value="Your $courses scores are bad";
        }
        elseif($value<75){
            $sentence_value="Your $courses scores are good";
        }
        elseif($value<85){
            $sentence_value="Your $courses scores are great";
        }
        elseif($value<=100){
            $sentence_value="Your $courses scores are extraordinary";
        }
    } 
        echo"Value : $sentence_value";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="course" placeholder="course" />
        <input type="text" name="grade" placeholder="grade"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are checking if $courses is "physics" many times.  I think it's better to test for value and courses separately.

Comment: I update my answer, and provide a full sample! take a look @Phil_1984_

Comment: @HanArantes +1 For taking the time to explain ;)

Comment: Ty :)  @SamyQc! Maybe this will help!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with a switch case, much easier to understand. BTW, this should go in code review, not on Stack.

```
<?php
$value=70;
//$courses='physics'; //or 
$courses='math';

switch (true) {
    case $value <= 50:
        echo "Your ".$courses." scores are bad";
        break;
    case $value <= 75:
        echo "Your ".$courses." scores are enough";
        break;
    case $value <= 85:
        echo "Your ".$courses." scores are good";
        break;
    case $value <= 95:
        echo "Your ".$courses." scores are great";
        break;
    case $value <= 100:
            echo "Your ".$courses." scores are excellent";
        break;
    default:
            echo "Bug";
    break;
}
?>
```

Comment: you mean `switch (true) {`

Comment: @Federico You're right, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_grades($subject, $score) {
    $math = [
                50 => "bad",
                75 => "enough",
                85 => "good",
                100 => "great"
            ];
    $physics = [
                50 => "bad",
                75 => "good",
                85 => "great",
                100 => "extraordinary"
    ];

    if ($subject == 'math') {
        $grades = $math;
        $sentence = "Your math scores are "
    } else {
        $grades = $physics;
        $sentence = "Your physics scores are "
    }

    foreach ($grades as $k => $v){
        if ($score <= $k){
            $result = $v;
        }
    }

    return $sentence . $result;
}

echo get_grades("math",50);
```